# Rounding before converting to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

For presentations sake I have a value that I want to show to only two decimal places before converting to varchar

```
select '£' + cast(round(amount,2) as varchar (10))
```

This works fine and would display the result as, say, £300.00. However the 'amount' also needs to be divided by 100 as part of the query.  When I add that in to the code...

```
select '£' + cast(round(amount/100,2) as varchar (10))
```

..it displays as £3.000000.  Is there any way to remove the extra 0s so only two are shown after the decimal point?

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but the syntax is SQL Server.

Comment: Are you using MySQL? you cannot convert it using varchar

Comment: Sorry just SQL Server.  Have removed the wrong tag

Answer (score 2):

Just use `format()`:

```
select '£' + format(amount, 2)
```

This also adds in commas, which seems desirable.

If you don't want the commas, then don't use `round()`, cast to a `decimal` type:

```
select '£' + cast(cast(round(amount, 2) as decimal(10, 2)) as varchar(10))
```

`round()` does change the *value*, but it doesn't change the storage mechanism.  The `cast( . .. as varchar)` doesn't know -- or care -- how many significant values are in the result.

EDIT (for SQL Server):

Instead of `format()` you can use the `str()` function:

```
select '£' + ltrim(str(amount, 10, 2))
```

Or the last method of converting to a decimal before the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of amount column? cast the round part into float

```
select '£' + cast(round(cast(8375.8734/100 as float),2) as varchar (100));
```

Result is

```
£83.76
```

Also this should done in the front end application and not in sql